# How to return a file path to the controller to parse a JSON file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a very simple view that will prompt a user to select a `JSON` file and then parse it.

Here is the relevant code from the view...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSampleDataJSON", "Event"))
{
   <input type="file" name="GetJSONFile" /><br>
   <input type="submit" />
}
```

Here is the method from the controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult AddSampleDataJSON(FormCollection form)
  {
        string path = ??
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(path))
         {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            List<Event> events = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Event>>(json);
         }
         return View();
  }
```

The question then is how do I access the full path so I can send it to the `StreamReader` to eventually parse the `JSON`. I don't see it in the `FormCollection` object.

Comment: You cant for security reasons (a browser only sends the file name and does not expose a uses file system). You parameter needs to be `HttpPostedFileBase GetJSONFile` and it will be populated with the file contents. And you need to set the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute in the form tag

Comment: As a parameter going into the method?  It comes in as null even after I added that attribute.  And the file I'm choosing is indeed a JSON file.

Comment: Then you did not set it correctly. (and it makes no difference what type of file it is)

Comment: I had to match the name of the element in the view with the variable name.  Now it works!

Comment: That is what my first comment stated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to access the client path to the file. You'll only see the file name.

You should set the encoding to `multipart/form-data` in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSampleDataJSON", "Event", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
     <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" /><br>
     <input type="submit" />
}
```

And in your controller change your input parameter to [HttpPostedFileBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx), with the parameter name being the same as the `name` parameter in the form:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSampleDataJSON(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(uploadedFile.InputStream))
    {
        string json = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<Event> events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Event>>(json);
    }

    return View();
}
```